# How to create button animation similar in calculator with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

Can someone help about create a winform animation like in Win7 Calculator when you hover mouse over button, currently i use bunch of image then looping it in backgroundworker, but i think its wrong, this is my code:

this occur when mouse enter,

```
private void bgTurnOn_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Label labelSender = (Label)e.Argument;
    int ii = labelSender.ImageIndex;
    for (int i = ii + 4; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        if (labelSender.AllowDrop)
        {
            labelSender.ImageIndex = i;
            Thread.Sleep(40);
        }
    }
}
```

and this when mouse leave

```
private void bgTurnOff_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Label labelSender = (Label)e.Argument;
    int ii = labelSender.ImageIndex;
    for (int i = ii; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (!labelSender.AllowDrop)
        {
            labelSender.ImageIndex = i;
            Thread.Sleep(80);
        }
    }
}
```

note: I just use AllowDrop so I do not bother to declare new variable, i have 42 button, so i think i need more efficient solution.

Comment: You can always make a user control out of it, so you won't need to look at it or do it for every button. But in general, if you want many effects and slides and animations, etc... You should probably go WPF.

Comment: sorry but I'm new at this, I can make a simple usercontrol, but what about animation, can you show an example.

Comment: You imitated animation pretty well. You just need to wrap this with a UserControl like `MyAnimatedButton : Button`

Comment: What animation do you want, exactly? Some of them can easily be calculated without images, which is preferred.

Comment: Maybe you can open up calculator if you on windows7, try hover your mouse over button, thats exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want a glow effect, so you can use the next idea:

- Make an `OpacityPictureBox : PictureBox` which supports opacity (in levels of 1-100 or double 0-1). See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26878/Making-Transparent-Controls-No-Flickering) for more information.
- Add two public const int values of `MaxOpacity` and `MinOpacity` to the `OpacityPictureBox` class, for easy and safe range checks from the outside. The values might be 0, 100 or 0, 1, or something else, depending on your implementation of opacity.
- Make an `AnimatedPictureBox : UserControl` which holds 1 `PictureBox` named `pbNormal` and 1 `OpacityPictureBox` named `opbHover`, both `Dock = DockStyle.Fill`, and one timer named `timer`. Make sure that `pbNormal` is below `opbHover`.
- Have three public properties:

  - `Normal` of type `Image` which delegates into `pbNormal.Image`
  - `Hover` of type `Image` which delegates into `opbHover.Image`
  - `AnimationInterval` of type `int` which delgates into `timer.Interval`
- In the constructor of the `AnimatedPictureBox`, after calling `InitializeComponents`, do `opbHover.Opacity = 0;`. You can also do `this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;` if you want the cursor to change into a hand when hovering over it.
- Have a private members: `_animationDirection` of type `int`, which will be -1 or 1.
- Have a private method that starts an animation in a given direction:

Code:

```
private void Animate(int animationDirection)
{
    this._animationDirection = animationDirection;
    this.timer.Start();
}
```

- Override `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseLeave`:

Code:

```
 protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
 {
     this.Animate(1);
     base.OnMouseEnter(e);
 }

 protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
 {
     this.Animate(-1);
     base.OnMouseEnter(e);
 }
```

- Listen to `timer.Tick` event and with this:

Code:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var hoverOpacity = this.opbHover.Opacity + this._animationDirection;

    if (hoverOpacity < OpacityPictureBox.MinOpacity ||
        hoverOpacity > OpacityPictureBox.MaxOpacity)
    {
        this.timer.Stop();
        return;
    }

    this.opbHover.Opacity = hoverOpacity;
}
```

Comment: There will still be some things to fix, like maybe parents issues, etc... But this is the general direction I would go for.